# python function not defined even when present in locals()

Tags: python

```
import inspect
from functools import wraps

def add_value_checks(*settings):
    def wrapping_function(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            code = inspect.getsource(func)
            hoax_code = code[code.find('\n')+1:code.find(':')+2]
            hoax_code += '\treturn inspect.currentframe()\n'
            if func.__name__ == 'run':
                hoax_code = hoax_code.replace('run', 'run_hoax', 1)
                print(hoax_code)
                exec(hoax_code)
                print(locals())
                frame = run_hoax(*args, **kwargs)
            targs, Args, Kwargs, values = inspect.getargvalues(frame)
            for i in targs:
                print("    %s = %s" % (i, values[i]))

        return wrapper
    return wrapping_function

@add_value_checks()
def run(a, b, c=True, d=5):
    print("Hello World")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run(3,4)
```

I see that the function `run_hoax()` is present in `locals()` but still I get **NameError: name 'run_hoax' is not defined**. What can be the possible reason for this?

Simple examples such as these work pretty fine:

```
In [1]: code = "def fun():\n\tprint(3)"

In [2]: exec(code)

In [3]: fun()
3
```

I can't understand what is the problem over here.

Comment: where do you define it?

Comment: @JoeIddon I define it in the variable `hoax_code` and compile the code with `exec()` method

Comment: Why the import inspect?

Comment: @marcuse what I am doing here is, in the `hoax_code` modifying the code of the method `run()` so that I get the frame object of that method (hoax method) which would be enough for my further computation

Comment: `frame = locals()['run_hoax'](*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: @Avezan bravo, why in the hell does that work and not normally?

Comment: Cut it short understand from here `globals()['run_hoax'] = locals()['run_hoax']`, now you can do normal `run_hoax(...)`.

Comment: @Avezan still not clear what's happening over here, do you mean my call to the method automatically assumes I am calling some function present in `globals()`?

Answer (score 1):

The example you've posted stops working when you put it inside a function:

```
In [4]: def f():
   ...:     code = "def foo():\n\treturn 1"
   ...:     exec(code)
   ...:     print(locals())
   ...:     return foo()
   ...: 

In [5]: f()
{'foo': <function foo at 0x7f780dcb48c8>, 'code': 'def foo():\n\treturn 1'}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-0ec059b9bfe1> in <module>()
----> 1 f()

<ipython-input-4-fd87a1e83c39> in f()
      3     exec(code)
      4     print(locals())
----> 5     return foo()

NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```

Functions are special, because they introduce a separate local scope. The variables inside that scope are fixed when the function is compiled (the number and names of the variables, not their values). You can see that by inspecting a function's `.__code__.co_varnames` attribute:

```
In [7]: f.__code__.co_varnames
Out[7]: ('code',)
```

That fixed registry of variable names is what is used when names are looked up from inside the function. And that registry isn't updated when you're calling `exec`.

The approach shown by [@Avezan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50838516/python-function-not-defined-even-when-present-in-locals/50838777#comment88681162_50838516) works because it doesn't use a local variable -- it uses `locals`, which *is* updated by your exec call.

The solution by [@Ishan Srivastava](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50838777/857390) works because it executes your code in the *global* namespace, which doesn't have the limitation of being fixed at compile time.

See [this blogpost](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2015/12/how-lookup-works.html) for a very nice description of Python's name lookup mechanisms and of how `local` and `exec` relate to each other.

Comment: you meant *`globals`, which(interestingly enough) is updated by your exec call.*

Comment: @IshanSrivastava Well, `locals` is looked up in `globals`, but the `exec` call does update `locals` (as the `print(locals())` shows). It's just that `locals` is only an imperfect representation of the local namespace -- in particular, adding a new variable to `locals` does not make it available inside the function.